# In a Powershell script, some commands don't recognize PS Drive

Tags: powershell

The following script maps a network drive with the new-psdrive command.
It uses get-content to load the contents of an XML file to a variable.
Truncated lines modify the XML object.
Then it uses the XML save method to save the file.
The script gives the error "Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "Could not find a part of the path 'M:\folder3\pems.xml'."

```
clear
Remove-PSDrive M

New-PSDrive -Name M -Root "\\server1\share\folder1\folder2\" -PSProvider FileSystem
$uncpath = "\\server1\share\folder1\folder2\"

$xmlfileDrive = "M:\folder3\pems.xml"
$xmlfileUNC = $uncpath+"folder3\pems.xml"

Get-ChildItem M: 
Get-ChildItem $uncpath

#####Truncated code that manipulates $xmlfile
#####Calls outside executables that don't support UNC paths.

[xml]$scheme = Get-Content $xmlfileDrive
$scheme.Save($xmlfileDrive)
```

If I change the last line from

```
$scheme.Save($xmlfileDrive)
```

to

```
$scheme.Save($xmlfileUNC)
```

No error appears, and the script functions properly.
Note that the "Get-Content" command on the second to last line works properly regardless of which variable I use. And the "Get-ChildItem" commands give identical results.

Why would some commands recognize the mapped drive and others not?

I've tested this in both Powershell 5 and 7.

Comment: Did you make sure that `folder3` exists in the `\\server1\share\folder1\folder2\` path?

Comment: `$scheme.Save()` is _not_ a PowerShell command - it's a native .NET method, and .NET  doesn't know anything about PSDrives, hence the behavior you're seeing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding "-persist" to the "New-PSDrive" command. After that the save() method and all my external calls to executables recognized the drive.

As Mathias R Jesson stated, any commands that aren't native Powershell commands won't recognize the PSDrive object (unless -persist) is used.